# How to retrieve weather information from ipaddress

Tags: xml, yii, weather-api

I am working in Yii+extjs. i am creating weather module. I want to retrieve weather information from ipaddress of user. i got reference code from website="http://www.geoplugin.com/examples".
As per mentioned there, i had created getweather function as=

```
                  public function actionGetWeather()
        {
            $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            //The Data Science Toolkit URL
            $url = 'http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/ip2coordinates/';
            //Find the user's location from their IP.
            //*** You need the get_data function from the sample code
            $raw_geocode = json_decode( get_data( $url . $user_ip) );
            //Check if the user is in the US
            if ('US' === $raw_geocode->$user_ip->country_code) {
                //If yes, store their zip code in a variable, and print it
                $zip_code = $raw_geocode->$user_ip->postal_code;
                printf('<p>Your zip code is: %s</p>', $raw_geocode->$user_ip->postal_code);
            } else {
                //If the user isn't in the US, set a sip code that will work.
                $zip_code = '97211';
                //and print an error
                printf('<p>Sorry, this app does not work in %s.</p>', $raw_geocode->$user_ip->country_name);
            }

            //Print the raw data for debugging.
            printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($raw_geocode, true));
        }
```

i had included ParseXml class in my project also.
But above code is giving error as Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_data() at line " $raw_geocode = json_decode( get_data( $url . $user_ip) );" of getweather function. So what changes i needed? Please help me

Comment: Instead of posting all this unrelated code, just focus on the "real issue", which is `get_data` not being defined ..

Answer (score 0):

If you'r using curl, include definition of get_data() as..

```
function get_data($url)
{
     $ch = curl_init();
     $timeout = 5;
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
     $data = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     return $data;
}
```

Or, simply replace

```
     $raw_geocode = json_decode( get_data( $url . $user_ip) );
```

with...

```
     $raw_geocode = json_decode(file_get_contents( $url . $user_ip) );
```